# How to split string with delimeter | which have digits in it

Tags: java, string, split

I want to split this string :

```
String line = "04/25/17|13:00|Line 0";
```

into ("04/25/17","13:00","Line 0");

I tried 
`String[] parts[] = line.split("|");`
and I've got (0,4,/,2,5,/,7,1,3,:,0,0,L,i,n,e,0)
then I tried  `String[] parts[] = line.split("\\|");`
I got the same result

Please help!

Comment: [`line.split("\\|");` works.](https://ideone.com/LH7OZK)

Comment: "I got the same result" only reason where this could happen is when you didn't save/recompile your code.

Comment: yes it Works thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. But I would say that you can free to delete this question since it looks like there was no real problem to begin with. People who didn't save/recompile their code will most likely not search for solution to their problem under "split on |" subject.

Answer (score -1):

If your strings all having the same length you can work with substring():

```
String line = "04/25/17|13:00|Line 0";
String part1 = line.substring(0,7);
String part2 = line.substring(9,13);
String part3 = line.substring(15,line.length());
```

Comment: This isn't dynamic. What if he wanted to represent the year using 4 digits? You'd have to change all the substring arguments, which isn't scalable.

Comment: I'm aware of that. Out of that reason i wrote "if your strings all having the same length"

Comment: You can shorten `substring(15,line.length());` with simple `substring(15);`